# Why doesn't the `id` parameter of GTK3 Application::send_notification() seem to do anything?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to debug a python application that uses the GTK3 bindings to send and update a desktop notification. But it seems unable to update notifications; Instead it always creates a new one.

The GTK documentation for [Application.send_notification](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/method.Application.send_notification.html) says:

> `id` may be any string that uniquely identifies the event for the application. It does not need to be in any special format. For example, “new-message” might be appropriate for a notification about new messages.
>
> If a previous notification was sent with the same id, it will be replaced with notification and shown again as if it was a new notification. This works even for notifications sent from a previous execution of the application, as long as id is the same string.

When I try this minimal python example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk

n = Gio.Notification.new("one")

app = Gtk.Application()
app.set_application_id("org.example.Notifier")
app.register()
app.send_notification("my-id", n)
n.set_title("two")
app.send_notification("my-id", n)
```

I see that it does indeed create a new notification instead of updating.

The [Notification spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html) explains that sending a notification is done with a DBus RPC call to `Notify` on `org.freedesktop.Notification`. The RPC call returns a unique `uint32` that can be supplied later to another `Notify` call to update the notification.

By monitoring activity with `dbus-monitor` I can confirm that the update mechanism works with the `notify-send` command provided by `inotify` (which allows specifying the `uint32` by hand), tested with two different notification daemons (`xfce4-notifyd` and `dunst`). I can also see that, with my python example, the `uint32` is always zero, no matter what the `id` parameter is.

For the sake of completeness, I tried a minimal example in Rust:

```rust
use gtk::{self, gio::{Notification, ApplicationFlags, Cancellable}, Application};
use gtk::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let id = Some("1234");
    let not = Notification::new("one");
    let app = Application::new(Some("org.example.Notifier"), ApplicationFlags::default());
    app.register(Cancellable::NONE).expect("register failed");
    app.send_notification(id, &not);
    not.set_title("two");
    app.send_notification(id, &not);
}
```

Same problem, a second notification is created instead of updating the first one.

Why is this feature not working? Did the application forget to initialize some part of GTK? or is it a bug in GTK itself?